# Session values are getting null while redirect from one web application from another

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, iis-7, session-cookies

I have a two asp.net web applications called App1 and App2 which are hosted in same IIS. App1 and App2 connected with different SQL Server databases. Now what I want is to get logged into the App1 and I will redirect to the App2 by passing the username and password in query string which means I will bypass the login process over App2 and I want to go the Home page of App2. While I am redirecting to the App2, all the `Session[]` values are getting set to null. So that I am not able to get the any Session values in App2 for further purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are Application specific. So you can't use it to share data across the applications. If you still want to share data then serialize you session data and pass it to other application using POST. For that you have to create intermediate page and it should be called instead of calling target page directly. This page will contain following mark-up

```
<body onload="document.myForm.submit()">
    <form id="myForm" runat="Server" action="targetApplicationPage" method="POST">
       <asp:Literal id="lit" runat="server"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

and set literal value as serialized session value from code behind on page load.

Comment: actually i dont want to use the same or share  the session values from the App1 to App2. i am overrideing all the session values what are already stored on App1   in App2. but somehow the values are getting null in App2.even though i dont want to keep alive the session of App1 after redirecting to the App2, but i want to create a new sessions values  and those values should not get null means shouldn't clear at all.

Comment: If you want to override anyway then you shouldn't care about other values.